# Correctly serializing objects in java

Tags: java, object, serialization

can anyone help me to spot the mistake? I am trying to pass certain information (min/max/avg ages) from file people.txt (which consists of 200 lines like 'Christel ; MacKay ; 4"2' ; 38'), to another file, by serializing.
Here's the first class, where I process some info about these people:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class Person implements Serializable
    {
         private String firstname;
         private String lastname;
         private int age;

     public Person (String PersonFN, String PersonLN, int PersonA)
     {
         firstname = PersonFN;
         lastname = PersonLN;
         age = PersonA;
     }

     public String toString()
     {
          return "Name: "+firstname+" "+lastname+" Age: "+age;

     }

     public int getAge()
     {
         return age;
     }

    }
```

And another one, which does all the job:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.*;



public class Collection
{
    int min;
    int max;
    int total;

    private static ArrayList<Person> people;

    public Collection()
    {
        people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        min = 100;
        max = 1;
        total = 0;
    }

    BufferedReader fr = null;
    BufferedWriter fw = null;

    public void readFromFile() throws IOException
    {
        fr = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("people.txt"));
        String line = null;
        StringTokenizer st;
         while (fr.ready())
        {
            line = fr.readLine();
            st = new StringTokenizer(line);           
            String name = st.nextToken(";");
            String surname = st.nextToken(";").toUpperCase();
            String height = st.nextToken(";");
            int age =  Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(";").trim());
            Person p = new Person (name, surname, age);
            p.toString();
            people.add(p);

            //for the 2nd part
            if(age < min)
                min = age;
            if (age > max)
                max = age;
            total = total + age;

        }

    }

    public int minAge()
    {
        int minA = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
        {
            Person p = people.get(i);
            int age = p.getAge();
            if (age < minA)
            {
                minA = age;

            }
        }
        System.out.print(minA+"; ");
        return minA;
    }

    public int maxAge()
    {
        int maxA = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
        {
            Person p = people.get(i);
            int age = p.getAge();
            if (age > maxA)
            {
                maxA = age;

            }
        }
        System.out.print(maxA+"; ");
        return maxA;
    }

    public float avgAge()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++)
        {
            Person p = people.get(i);
            int age = p.getAge();
            sum = sum + age;
        }
        float avgA = sum / people.size();
        System.out.print(avgA);
        return avgA;


    }

    public int fastMinAge()
    {
        //System.out.print("Minimum age: " + min);
        return min;

    }

    public int fastMaxAge()
    {
        return max;
    }

     public float fastAvgAge()
     { 
         return total / people.size();
     }


    public void writeToFile(String filename) throws IOException
    {

         StringBuffer val = new StringBuffer ("Minimum age: ");
         val.append(fastMinAge());
         val.append("\n Maximum age: ");
         val.append(fastMaxAge());
         val.append("\n Average age: ");
         val.append(fastAvgAge());

         BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
         String outText = val.toString();
         out.write(outText);
         out.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Collection c = new Collection();
        c.readFromFile();

        for(Person d: people)
        {
            System.out.println(d);

        }
      c.minAge();
      c.maxAge();
      c.avgAge();
      c.fastMinAge();
      c.fastMaxAge();
      c.fastAvgAge();
      c.writeToFile("RESULTS.txt");

      String filename = "people.txt";
      //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
      ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
      os.writeObject(c);
      os.close();

      String filename1 = "results1.txt";
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename1);
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
      Collection p = (Collection) ois.readObject();
      ois.close();

    }

}
```

When I run the code, it creates the RESULTS.txt file and adds the correct information there. I'm sure there's something wrong with this exact part of code:

```
  String filename = "people.txt";
          //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
          ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));
          os.writeObject(c);
          os.close();

          String filename1 = "results1.txt";
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename1);
          ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
          Collection p = (Collection) ois.readObject();
          ois.close();
```

By the way, my people.txt file changes into "¬ķ {sr  java.io.NotSerializableException(Vx ē†5  xr java.io.ObjectStreamExceptiondĆäk¨9ūß  xr java.io.IOExceptionl€sde%š«  xr java.lang.ExceptionŠż>;Ä  xr java.lang.ThrowableÕĘ5'9wøĖ L causet Ljava/lang/Throwable;L 
detailMessaget Ljava/lang/String;[ 
stackTracet [Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;L suppressedExceptionst Ljava/util/List;xpq ~  t SD3lab1.Collectionur [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;F*<<ż"9  xp   sr java.lang.StackTraceElementa    Å&6Ż… I 
lineNumberL declaringClassq ~ L fileNameq ~ L 
methodNameq ~ xp˙˙˙˙t java.io.ObjectOutputStreampt writeObject0sq ~ 
˙˙˙˙q ~ pt writeObjectsq ~ 
   ©q ~ 
t Collection.javat mainsr &java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableListü%1µģˇ L listq ~ xr ,java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollectionB €Ė^÷ L ct Ljava/util/Collection;xpsr java.util.ArrayListxŅ™Ēa¯ I sizexp    w    xq ~ x", and I get these errors on the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: SD3lab1.Collection
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at SD3lab1.Collection.main(Collection.java:169)
```

MANY THANKS FOR ANY HELP

Comment: `Collection c = new Collection();` ??? why are you implementing collection ? that's an interface and you've got plenty of implementations you can use!

Comment: @OleksiyMartynov, c is from "Collection c = new Collection();", which I've used before, I'm definitely not sure how to do the serializing thing. Is it even in the right class?

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark `Collection` as `Serializable`

```
public class Collection implements Serializable {
```

In addition `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` are not serializable so need to be marked as `transient`

```
private transient BufferedReader fr;
private transient BufferedWriter fw;
```

Also using a class name such as `Collection` is bound to cause confusion. Consider renaming the class.

Comment: now I get "Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: results1.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)", and the people file changes like the last time, and it doesn't even create the "results1.txt" file.

Comment: The file `results1.txt` is never written by this program. Did you mean `RESULTS.txt`?

Comment: isn't it written here?
String filename1 = "results1.txt";
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename1);

Comment: Actually the only file that you can read in again is `people.txt` - `RESULTS.txt` has been written using a `BufferedWriter` so is incompatible with a `ObjectInputStream`

Comment: How do I create that "results1.txt" then? By the way, does anyone know what's with the changes of the people file?

Comment: That depends - do you want a regular text format or a serialized format. You already have examples of both in your code...

Comment: the task was to create both, so I'm struggling with the serialized one now